# Why doesn't it matter if it's Arcturian?

Tags: alien-franchise, aliens-1986

In *Aliens* there is a dialogue between the marines while at 'chow time' when Frost gets called out for sleeping with a male Acturian and defends it by saying "it doesn't matter when it's Arcturian, baby". But why doesn't it matter?

Comment: [Here's the script](https://www.techylib.com/en/view/shrewdnessmodern/aliens_script_final_draft_alien_legend).   And it's A**r**cturian.

Comment: For the record I looked through the Alien-related scripts [here](https://www.simplyscripts.com/genre/sci-fi-scripts.html) and didn't find another mention of Arctur*.   I would write an answer, but it would feel hypocritical on a question I don't think should be asked.

Comment: @Seamusthedog - It has been a while since I have watched any of the Aliens films, but I think before we can even have a shot at answering your question we would need to know what an "Arcturian" is in the Aliens franchise. I have a feeling that it was only mentioned the one time in the entire franchise. While I don't think the question should be downvoted, because it is legit, the only explanations we may have would have to be in the related comics or novels... With what you have said I think they were making fun of him for sleeping with someone (man or woman) that was really ugly...

Comment: Odin. Thanks, I only asked as there is always someone here who'll know regardless of how throw away the line in question is.

Comment: @Seamusthedog - The actor improvised the line. Apparently he was making a joke about how "pretty" Arcturian aliens (note, not human) are and how it doesn't really matter if you get a man or a woman. Unfortunately, the podcast I want to quote from is stuck behind a paywall.

Comment: @Seamusthedog - Latterly, the Arcturians were retconned as a non-sentient race of alien monkeys. Their external sexual characteristics are quite similar.

Comment: @Valorum - Retconned into bestiality?

Comment: @Adamant - The best kind of retcon

Comment: @Valorum  I'll trust you.

Comment: Would lack of a definitive answer mean this question has to be closed or become a matter of opinion?

Comment: @Seamusthedog - If I can get this podcast. I'll put together an answer. Basically it'll be the comment above (complete with transcript), plus an interview from Cameron where he says that he didn't give it much thought but assumed they were colonists and some stuff about the retcon.

Comment: @Valorum ta much, if you can't source what you're looking for just use above as answer and I'll except.

Comment: Let lesser men post unsourced answers. I have a reputation to consider

Comment: The way I remember the exchange the marines were bragging about their sexual exploits (I guess with Arcturians) but the one marine was putting down another marine by bragging along the lines of "at least MINE was a female."

Comment: @Valorum - It may say something about people's prejudices that they could not have the character be (gasp!) bisexual, but having them be into bestiality was considered A-OK.

Comment: These kind of lines imply a Alien universe in which extra-terrestrial species/civilizations are fairly commonplace although the timeline and the fact we only see the xenomorph and later the Engineers as examples which seem still novel enough to suggest otherwise -- that is, that ETs are not commonplace.